# Approach to Implementing a CSV Generator from Linear Information

Tags: c#, algorithm, csv

I have a pseudo-code question for a problem I've encountered. I have a binary file of recorded variable data at certain record rates (20Hz,40Hz, etc..). This information is linear in the file. For example if I have var1 and var2, I'd read from the file var1's data, then var2's data, then var1's next sample, etc...I'm pretty sure the best way to construct a CSV is by row. My original thought was to just read in the binary file and parse the information into a contemporary buffer/structure. Once all the binary data is read in then begin writing the CSV file by row. My only concern with this approach is memory consumption. There can be anywhere from 300-400 parameters recorded as high as 160HZ. That's a lot of data to have stored. I was wondering if there's any other approaches that are more efficient. Language I'm using is C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you have:

```
{ some large number of var1 samples }
{ some large number of var2 samples }
{ some large number of var3 samples }
```

And you want to create:

```
var1, var2, var3, etc.
var1, var2, var3, etc.
```

If you have enough memory to hold all of that data, then your first approach is the way to go.

Only you can say whether you have enough memory. If the file is all binary data (i.e. integers, floats, doubles, etc.), then you can get a pretty good idea of how much memory you'll need just by looking at the size of the file.

Assuming that you don't have enough memory to hold all of the data at once, you could easily process the data in two passes.

On the first pass, you read all of the `var1` data and immediately write it to a temporary file called `var1Data`. Then do the same with `var2`, `var3`, etc. When the first pass is done, you have N binary files, each one containing the data for that variable.

The second pass is a simple matter of opening all of those files, and then looping:

```
while not end of data
    read from var1Data
    read from var2Data
    read from var3Data
    etc.
    create structure
    write to CSV
```

Or, you could do this:

```
while not end of data
    read from var1Data
    write to CSV
    read from var2Data
    write to CSV
    etc.
```

Granted, it's two passes over the data, but if you can't fit all of the data into memory that's the way you'll have to go.

One drawback is that you'll have 300 or 400 files open concurrently. That shouldn't be a problem. But there is another way to do it.

On the first pass, read, say, the first 100,000 values for each parameter into memory, create your structures, and write those to the CSV. Then make another pass over the file, reading items 100,000 to 199,999 for each parameter into memory and append to the CSV. Do that until you've processed the entire file.

That might be easier, depending on how your binary file is structured. If you know where each parameter's data starts in the file, and all the values for that parameter are the same size, then you can seek directly to the start for that parameter (or to the 100,000th entry for that parameter), and start reading. And once you've read however many values for `var1`, you can seek directly to the start of the `var2` data and start reading from there. You skip over data you're not ready to process in this pass.

Which method to use will depend on how much memory you have and how your data is structured. As I said, if it all fits into memory then your job is very easy. If it won't fit into memory, then if the binary file is structured correctly you can do it with multiple passes over the input file, on each pass skipping over the data you don't want for that pass. Otherwise, you can use the multiple files method, or you can do multiple passes over the input, reading sequentially (i.e. not skipping over data).